# Securing Web Application with Spring Boot is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have implemented an example from official spring guide:
[Securing a Web Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

I put three html files /resources/templates:

**HELLO.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HOME HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**LOGIN HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The MVC configuration is

```
@Configuration

public class MVCConfig {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

    }
}
```

The security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

When I run the application and open the 127.0.0.1:8080/ link, I encounter the error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I removed the thymeleaf tags from the files and made the files static. Then I moved them to /static. 
The login form is as follows:

```
<form "/login" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
```

And changed the SecurityConfig:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("**/login.html**").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
```

Now I can open the location 127.0.0.1:8080/login.html, but no authentication happens after submitting the form. (403 Error is shown)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and you should have already solved it. Anyway, if someone else has this problem, I am also new in the spring and had the same problem as you in this tutorial. So I tried to solve the thymeleaf problem and everything started to work correctly, including authentication.

All I did was include the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```